# Resolving a FileNotFound issue when running a custom test type for Visual Studio

Tags: automated-tests, vs-extensibility, visual-studio-test-runner

I have implemented a custom test type for Visual Studio. The custom test type reads its test elements from dlls. My ITip implementation is working like a charm. The test elements are loaded and are displayed on the Test View tool window.

When I select the test elements and run them they end up in a Not Executed status. While debugging this issue I found out that a FileNotFoundException is thrown from QTAgent32.exe. It tells me that it cannot find the dll that defines the test cases. Also, it fails before my TestAdapter.Initialize method is called. I copied my test dll to the PrivateAssemblies directory of Visual studio. When I do that my test elements pass. I can also debug the code in my custom test adapter. So, the meaning of all of this is that QTAgent32.exe cannot find my test dll in its original directory.

My question is what should I do to make QTAgent32 find my test dll in the original directory? For completenes I add my Tip Load method code:

```
public override ICollection Load(string location, ProjectData projectData, IWarningHandler warningHandler)
{
    Trace.WriteLine("Started RegexTestTip Load.");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(location))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("File location was not specified!", "location");
    }

    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(location);
    if (!fileInfo.Exists)
    {
        throw new ErrorReadingStorageException(
                string.Format("Could not find a file on the specified location: {0}", location));
    }
    var result = new List<ITestElement>();
    var extension = fileInfo.Extension.ToLower();
    if (extension != ".dll")
    {
        return result;
    }

    Assembly testAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(location);
    var testClasses = testAssembly.GetTypes().
        Where(t => Attribute.IsDefined(t, typeof(RegexTestClassAttribute)));

    foreach (Type testClass in testClasses)
    {
        PropertyInfo property = testClass.GetProperties().
            SingleOrDefault(p => Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof(TestedRegexAttribute)));
        if (property == null || !TestedRegexAttribute.Validate(property))
        {
            throw new InvalidDataInStorageException("A Regex test must define a Tested Regex property with type Regex");
        }
        var testCases = testClass.GetProperties().
            Where(p => Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof(RegexTestCaseAttribute)));

        foreach (PropertyInfo testCase in testCases)
        {
            if (!RegexTestCaseAttribute.Validate(testCase))
            {
                throw new InvalidDataInStorageException("A test case property must return a String value.");
            }
            var testElement = new RegexTestElement(property, testCase);
            testElement.Storage = location;
            testElement.Name = testCase.Name;
            testElement.Description = "A simple description";
            testElement.ProjectData = projectData;
            result.Add(testElement);
        }
    }
    Trace.WriteLine("Finished RegexTestTip Load.");
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Always Highlight the Question to understand the key points very quickly :)

Comment: @Venkat - what do you mean highlight? Make it bold?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just putting the dll in the same directory as the executable?  Forgive the obviousness of that, but sometimes its the really simple things that bite us.  But it's in the GAC right?

Comment: Like I said in the question I did it. I put my dll in Visual studio's PrivateAssemblies directory an it solve the problem. But this is not a solution since you don't copy each unit test dll to Visual Studio's PrivateAssemblies directory.

Comment: Ah I didn't read that correctly.  Some things to try - have you stopped and started the agent?  Perhaps it needs to be fully restarted according to this link, given that it is misbehaving:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/girishp/archive/2012/03/09/tfs-2010-build-controlling-qtagent32-exe-the-test-agent-process-startup-and-termination-from-within-build-workflow.aspx  It doesn't state your specific issue, but I'm wondering if perhaps there is something related here... you can use "sc \\mymachine stop vsttagent" and "sc \\mymachine start vsttagent"

Comment: sorry I don't think this is relevant since I am running my tests from visual studion and not from TFS.

Comment: That is correct, and as I mentioned I most certainly would have left it as a comment rather than an answer, but it just isn't an answer.  But thankfully this morning I find myself over the comment hurdle in terms of reputation.  I hope you find a solution to the problem.  Rgds....Matt